# Howto insert awk command in perl script?

Tags: linux, perl, awk

I want to add this awk command on my script but keep getting error. I have put inside " " but still getting error.

```
system("awk -F"\t" '{ for ( i=1; i<=2; i++ ) { printf "%s\t", $i } printf "\n"; }' myfile file2"};
```

the errors are

> String found where operator expected
>   at host_parse line 21, near "t" '{ for
>   ( i=1; i<=2; i++ ) { printf ""
>
> Unquoted string "a" may clash with
>   future reserved word at myfile line
>   58.
>
> Unquoted string "a" may clash with
>   future reserved word at myfile line
>   58.
>
> syntax error at myfile line 21, near
>   "" awk -F"\"

Thanks.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to mix Awk and Perl? They serve the same purpose, so if you have one, there should be no need for the other.

Comment: Because sometimes the right tool for the job is the tool you already know how to use.

Comment: Yoy can try to translate awk scripts to perl, with this useful tool: a2p http://perldoc.perl.org/a2p.html

Comment: I not only want to uparrow @larsmans comment, I want to *bold* it, *italicize* it and put it in H1 style!

Comment: @Axeman: Don't forget red and blink.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the trickiest parts about using the `system` command is using quotes in a way that will get the correct command passed to the operating system. Perl's [`q//`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlop#Quote_and_Quote-like_Operators____________________) construction can be very helpful for this:

```
# treat everything between the @...@ as uninterpolated string
system( q@awk -F"\t" '{ for ( i=1; i<=2; i++ ) { printf "%s\t", $i } 
          printf "\n"; }' myfile file2@ );
```

Comment: Passing an array to system is even better. Quoting issues disappear.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your immediate question, you're tripping over the default behavior of Perl's `system` operator. Usually, it's a great convenience for the shell to parse the command, but sometimes, as as you've seen, having multiple levels of encoding is a pain—or even a [security vulnerability](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Safe-Pipe-Opens).

You can bypass the shell's quoting entirely with the `system LIST` and `exec LIST` forms. In your case, change your code to

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @cmd = (
  "awk",
  "-F", "\t",
  '{ for ( i=1; i<=2; i++ ) {
       printf "%s\t", $i
     }
     printf "\n";
   }',
   "myfile", "file2",
);

system(@cmd) == 0 or warn "$0: awk exited " . ($? >> 8);
```

You don't have to use the temporary array, but I don't like the resulting code with a multi-line command and a check for success.

Given `myfile` containing

```
1  2   3   4
foo bar baz
oui oui monsieur
```

and `file2` with

```
a   b   c
d   e   f   g
```

(where the separators in both cases are TAB characters), then the output is

```
1  2   
foo bar 
oui oui 
a   b   
d   e
```

They're invisible, but each line of output above has a trailing TAB.

Doing the same in Perl is straightforward. For example,

```
sub print_first_two_columns {
  foreach my $path (@_) {
    open my $fh, "<", $path or die "$0: open $path: $!";

    while (<$fh>) {
      chomp;
      my(@cols) = (split /\t/)[0 .. 1];
      print join("\t", @cols), "\n";
    }

    close $fh;
  }
}
```

The part that may not be obvious is taking a [slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) of the values returned from `split`, but what's happening is simple in concept. A slice allows you to grab data at multiple indices (0 and 1 in this case, *i.e.*, the first and second columns). The [range-operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) expression `0 .. 1` evaluates to the list 0 and 1. If you decide later you want the first *four* columns, you'd change it to `0 .. 3`.

Call the sub above as in

```
print_first_two_columns "myfile", "file2";
```

Note that the code isn't exactly equivalent: it doesn't preserve the trailing TAB characters.

From the command line, it's even simpler:

```
$ perl -lane '$,="\t"; print @F[0,1]' myfile file2 
1   2
foo bar
oui oui
a   b
d   e
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the shell to interpret any redirection (or other shell facilities), so it would be better to pass a list of arguments to `system()`

```
system 'awk', '-F', "\t", 
   '{for (i=1; i<=2; i++) {printf "%s\t", $i}; print ""}',
   'myfile', 'file2';
```